# search for multiple condition and then redirect output

Tags: io-redirection, file-search

How can you search for all lines containing “55=MSFT” and not containing the string “OPEN” in a file, then redirect the output to a file named MSFTFILE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` for the first string, then pipe the output to `grep -v` which matches all lines without OPEN, then direct the output to MSFTFILE.

Edit:
Use `-h` option of grep to suppress filenames in grep output if required.

```
grep -h -- '55=MSFT' * | grep -v OPEN > MSFTFILE
```

(however note that the second `grep` may match on the filenames)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'next if /OPEN/; print if /55=MSFT/;' file > MSFTFILE
```

This should be pretty much self explanatory: next line if this line matches `OPEN` and print if it matches `55=MSFT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/55=MSFT/ && ! /OPEN/'

sed -e '/55=MSFT/!d' -e /OPEN/d

grep 55=MSFT | grep -v OPEN

perl -ne 'print if /55=MSFT/ && !/OPEN/'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat filename | grep "55MSFT" > MSFTFILE
```